# What sort of Math series is this, what's the equation?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math, series

I'm not able to figure out what the actual formula or name for this series is:

3 : 5; 4 : 10 ; 5 : 15; etc..

Here is the code:

```
        i = 4
        n = 2
        while i <= granularity and i != 3:
            if (i == granularity):
                return 5 * n

            n += 1
            i += 1
        return 5
```

HERE IS MORE OF THE CODE I USED TO SOLVE THIS SERIES:

```
    def getChartData(self, sym, timescale="last_day", intraday="Y", granularity="3", ytdate="False", extdhrs="n"):
    dateMin = ""
    dateMax = ""
    alt = "hi" if timescale == "last_hi" else "lo" if timescale == "last_lo" else "cl" if timescale == "last_cl" else ""
    href = ""
    content = ""
    sorted_content = {}

    def granFac():
        gran = int(granularity)
        i = 4
        n = 2
        while i <= gran and i != 3:
            if (i == gran):
                return (dt.now() - td(minutes=(5 * n))).strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")

            n += 1
            i += 1
    
    return (dt.now() - td(minutes=5)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code snippet?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Those are fine, but like with non-homework questions, please show what you tried and how you are stuck (so that the answers can be actually useful to your learning)

Comment: Sorry, nothing to do with numpy just figured those users would appreciate this sort of question. It isn't homework I am just working on some charting software. I've already solved the code I more or less want to explore the math behind it.

Comment: "3 = 5"? That doesn't make any sense in Python and not much sense in math. Maybe you mean an input of `3` returns `5`, like `f(3) = 5`? In any case, Stack Overflow is about programming, not math, so what's your programming question? If you actually want to ask about math, there's [math.se].

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot! A function with an incremental range starting at 3 with a { 5 | domain}.     https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/domain-and-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is most likely a combination of two suggestions. It turns out to be a function with a range that starts at 3 and increases by one, and a domain that has a set in multiples of five starting at 5.

```
function { 3, 4, 5.. }( 5 | {} )
-or-
function { x ≥ 3, x ∈ Z+ }( {x|x ∈ Z+, x≡0 (mod 5)} )
```

It seems there is a couple ways to write it depending on which crowd you come from.

How I found the answer:

[Domain & Range](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/domain-and-range)

[Notating Multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331716/notation-for-multiple-of-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, ...` can be described as an [arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).